# how to pass string arguments in java as argument at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, parameter-passing

I am new to Java I need help with as how can I take values at runtime when a Java file is executed. I have Java program where the values of host,user, password and command is hardcoded, how can I parmeterize it.
eg,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host="ssh.journaldev.com";
        String user="sshuser";
        String password="sshpwd";
        String command1="ls -ltr";
        try{....
```

Can we make any changes such that at runtime on cmdline i can pass all values.
eg.
`java -jar testjava ssh.journaldev.com sshuser sshpwd "ls -ltr"`
this should be executed.

Comment: [Command-Line Arguments - Oracle Official Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is done like the following:

```
String name = args[0];
String user = args[1];
String password=args[2];
String command1=args[3];
```

Comment: how can i test it do i need to create the jar and then run it, i have eclipse and in the console i wrote the code, is there a way to test this in eclipse.